# Preferred way to make HTTP[S] requests

Tags: python, http, httprequest, urllib2, urllib

I need to make HTTP and HTTPS requests using POST, GET and other methods and specifying headers and timeouts.

On the Internet there are many examples, and they are all different:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

or

```
    fetcher = urllib2.build_opener()
    fetcher.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'aaaa=%s' % aaaa))
    res = fetcher.open(settings.ABC_URL)
```

or

```
req = urllib2.Request(url=url)
req.add_header('X-Real-IP', request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
req.add_header('Cookie', request.META['HTTP_COOKIE'])
req.add_header('User-Agent', request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

or

```
handler = urllib.urlopen('http://...')
response = handler.read()
```

I guess under the hood some of these methods use the same mechanism.

There also other examples using `httplib`, `httplib2`. And i read urllib2 is the preferred lib to use.

Which one is preferred method? Which advantages and disadvantages each of them has?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try out the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)-module which fixes the URL/download library madness in Python.

Comment: But surely you have access to the filesystem where you can create folders and files? With Pythons import mechanism, you don't need to install packages via easy_install or pip (albeit better, especially in a virtualenv), you can download requests and put the folder "requests" from the tarball into your working directory. The import will work and usage stays the same, unless your Python interpreter starts in another directory, then you need to modify PYTHONPATH or sys.path. If that doesn't work, please explain why (and how) you are limited to the standard library.

Comment: I mean i don't make such decisions in my project, and i fear i won't be able to justify usage of another third-party module

Comment: It should be easy to convince your bosses or co-workers if you show them your original post and code examples from the requests homepage. Let them compare. No serious developer will prefer the standard library over requests :)

Comment: OK, my team leader got convinced. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with Fabian, you should use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Why? Perhaps the author himself summarizes it best here:

[Kenneth Reitz's talk "Python For Humans" -- section on why `urllib2` is "the worst API" ever](http://python-for-humans.heroku.com/#24).

Comment: Well, from the talk i got part of the answer - there no preferred way - all of the stuff in the standard lib related to HTTP is ugly